# Content Negotiation for Stylesheet Fails

Tags: mime-types, content-negotiation

I have an Apache server with MultiViews, here's my directory layout:

```
/style.css [text/css]
/style.xsl [text/xsl]
/index.xml [application/xml]
```

In my index.xml file, I reference the XSL:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="/style"?>
```

In the XSL, I reference the CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style" />
```

This approach doesn't work in any browser that I have tried.

In Firefox-16.0.1 I see the following message:

```
Error loading stylesheet: An XSLT stylesheet does not have an XML mimetype:
```

I debug the HTTP conversation, I notice that Firefox is sending:

```
Accept: */*
```

Firefox is requesting any type of content, so Apache chooses to send /style.css.

I would expect web browsers who require specific content types to send explicit Accept headers for those content-types.

I was prepared to submit a bug, when I found two others which explicitly documented getting rid of the Accept constraints.

- [reduce verbosity of Accept header for fetching XSLT](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=656251)
- [stylesheet link header doesn't support official XSLT media type](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=655238)

I can work around this by putting the extensions in the file names, but this should work the same way as content negotiation for images, as discussed in the [W3C blog](http://www.w3.org/QA/2006/02/content_negotiation.html). The benefit is that they can add a new content type later without having to update any of their documents.

Is this a bug, or am I getting something wrong?